# Redirect 401 "authorization required page" to custom page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-401

Is there a simple way I can encode a front-end php redirect to a custom page upon error?

I have a page in a directory protected by an .htaccess password, but if you cancel the system dialog or enter the wrong details, you get a plain html message in the browser and have to navigate back.

Would be great to have custom error pages as a solution to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the .htaccess file, just add

```
ErrorDocument 401 /401.html
```

And change 401.html to the name of the file you want to display.