# How can I style a .htaccess password protection promp?

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, alert

I've just been messing around with setting a password protected directory on my webserver (so as to store hot copies of backups etc.) and was wondering if there's any way I may be able to style the password prompt that appears when a user attempts to access this page.

[image: screenshot of the default prompt]

As it stands nobody will notice my nice little note, which makes me sad.

[image: my prompt]

It seems to display similarly to a standard .js alert, though I've been unable to find a way to specify any css classes I may be able to alter, as the "alert" box does not show up in devtools, just the page bahind it:

[image: screenshot of html source]

Any advice / tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't edit the authentication login box itself, it's different for every browser and its implemented as part of the browser's internals (for example, a snippet of Chrome's Code dealing with the Login Title: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/app/generated_resources.grd&q=%22Authentication%20Required%22&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=3552).

What you can do is to create a custom php login page (with popover if you want) to display:

[Redirect 401 "authorization required page" to custom page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479493/redirect-401-authorization-required-page-to-custom-page)

[Custom Login with htaccess through HTML/PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978761/custom-login-with-htaccess-through-html-php)

[Replace Htaccess popup box with a html form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841420/replace-htaccess-popup-box-with-a-html-form)

Comment: Thanks, this sorted it out for me! Great workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 401 /401.html
```

Then in your root directory (where your index.html is) make your own 401.html file. If you want to make the login work, however, you'll need a server side language like PHP.

Comment: Please note that this only shows the 401 Unauthorized page _after_ the user enters an incorrect input. It does not modify the Alert dialog.

Answer (score -1):

From [how to change the style of alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box), you cannot change the style of an alert box unless you make your own Alert Dialog (See [Here](http://www.tutorialscollection.com/jquery-alert-how-to-use-alert-box-in-jquery-with-code-and-running-example/) for an example)